# copy value of cell into textbox

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

this is what i would like to do:

each time a checkbox is clicked,
- the cell next to it will be copied
    -locate this textbox
    -find the end of string in the  textbox if any
- and pasted the copied cell (values) into this textbox

i manage to figure out how to make the checked cell copied, but all the codes i tried to paste it into the textbox is not working.

below is what i've got so far

```
Sub checkBoxHandler()

    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, 1).Select    ' 1 COL below checkbox
    Selection.Copy  'copy the cell next to the checkbox
    Call UpdateTextBox


    Set shp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub UpdateTextBox()
    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard

    strPaste = DataObj.GetText(1)    ' get ext from clipboard


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub checkBoxHandler()
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim sTxt As String
    Set Shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    sTxt = Shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, 1).Value2 'Verify this line against the cell you want to copy as the cell below is .Offset(1,0)

    Call UpdateTextBox(ActiveSheet, sTxt)
    Set Shp = Nothing

End Sub


Sub UpdateTextBox(WshTrg As Worksheet, sTxt As String)
Dim oOleObj As OLEObject
    Set oOleObj = WshTrg.OLEObjects("TextBox1") 'replace TextBox1 with the name of your Text Box
    With oOleObj.Object
        .Value = .Value & " " & sTxt
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Tried to run this but it gives error "400".

Comment: when i try to step into it, it shows run-time error "13", Type mismatch.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i tried it again. i must have done something wrong the other day (i think i was still using the textbox from the insert ribbon when i run your code. with Active X Textbox,your code works like a charm too.. ThankS!!

Comment: Just trying my luck to ask it here.. This project that has worked perfectly well before no longer does. Everytime I click a checkbox, a prompt saying " Object does not support this property or method". Any idea why?

Comment: Which line is giving the error? what changes had been done to the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,make sure sheets and textbox name match yours.

```
Sub ChangeText()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim sh As Shape

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Textbox 1")
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell    'find the range of the button clicked.

    sh.TextFrame.Characters.Text = r.Offset(1,1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this out. Only the detail (cell next to the checkbox) of the latest checkbox checked get transferred.